# How to return value when there's no input in array method?

Tags: java, arrays

So, I have to write a program that counts the most repeated number in an array (e.g. 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3) and then tells the user what number is it (3). Finally, an online compiler tests my code and sees if my output is correct.

[Here are the inputs from the program.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Ubt6.png)
My issue is the last input, which is nothing. I tried to return a value but I couldn't.

Here's my code excluding the main method (Java):

Edit: Thank you everyone. I'm an idiot.

```
public int lengthOfLongestRun(int[] values) {

    if (values == null){
        return 0;
    }

    int lastVal = values[0];
    int currentLength = 1;
    int longestLength = 1;

    for (int i = 1; i < values.length; i++) {
        if (values[i] == lastVal)
            currentLength++;
        else
            currentLength = 1;

        lastVal = values[i];

        if (currentLength > longestLength)
            longestLength = currentLength;
    }
    return longestLength;
}
```

Comment: What do you think the length of the array is in that case?

Comment: I am confused. You say that you need to print the repeating number butthe function returns the number of repeats. That is not the same thing.

Comment: Are the arrays always sorted? If they are not sorted, this solution won't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the array is empty you need to check the length and return zero if the length of the array is zero.

Right now you have added a condition already for null check. Just extend that and add another condition for empty array aswell.

```
public int lengthOfLongestRun(int[] values)
   {

if(values == null || values.length == 0){ // code added here
  return 0;
}


int...
...
```

That should solve your problem.

I can see another potential bug here. Your loop starting at position `1`

```
for (int i = 1; i < values.length; i++)
  {
```

What if the biggest number lies at position `1` ? You are not seeing the bug because all your input arrays starting with value `1`.

Answer (score 0):

If the input array is `[]`, its length is zero. So just check for that:

```
if (values.length == 0) {
  return 0;
}
```

Note that it's maybe better not to return 0 in the null case: it's an invalid input, so don't give a valid output. Throw a `NullPointerException` or `IllegalArgumentException`, for instance.

You can also write the loop so as not to need to handle the zero case separately:

```
int longestLength = 0;
int i = 0;
while (i < values.length) {
  int start = i++;
  while (i < values.length && values[i] == values[start]) {
    ++i;
  }
  longestLength = Math.max(longestLength, i - start);
}
return longestLength;
```

Comment: @vefthym no. Null is a logically invalid input, so a runtime exception is more appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

You should check array size

```
if(values == null || array.length == 0){
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if(values == null || values.length == 0){
  return 0;
}
```